# Represent weights in self-loop nodes using NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to represent a Graph, given and adjacency matrix, using networkX.

I managed to represent the graph with weights, however, self-loops do not show the weights. I have tried several things.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the adjacency matrix
adj_matrix = [[5, 1, 3, 0],
              [0, 10, 2, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [4, 0, 1, 0]]

# Create a directed graph from the adjacency matrix
G = nx.DiGraph()
for i in range(len(adj_matrix)):
    for j in range(len(adj_matrix)):
        if adj_matrix[i][j] != 0:
                G.add_edge(i, j, weight=adj_matrix[i][j], label=adj_matrix[i][j])

# Draw the graph with edge labels and node labels
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1000)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=2)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
node_labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels=node_labels)

plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Networkx currently does not properly support the labeling of curved edges, including self-loops, as it ignores the edge path and simply places the label in the center (by default) of the straight line between the source and target node positions. For self-loops, the label position ends up being the node position itself. Various fixes [have been discussed for years](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3813) but none is implemented (AFAIK).

If you are open to using other libraries, you can use [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), which is a visualization library I wrote and maintain that works well with networkx. Crucially, it uses the edge paths to position the edge labels.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph

adj_matrix = np.array([[5, 1, 3, 0],
                       [0, 10, 2, 1],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [4, 0, 1, 0]])

sources, targets = np.where(adj_matrix)
weights = adj_matrix[sources, targets]
edges = list(zip(sources, targets))
edge_labels = dict(zip(edges, weights))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Graph(edges, edge_labels=edge_labels, edge_label_position=0.66, arrows=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to make your graph spread out more? Like with a spring layout or something?

Comment: @EvanMata Netgraph uses the spring layout by default but there are [other layouts](https://netgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/node_layout.html) available. If the plot elements are too large w.r.t. the size of the graph, then you can either decrease the `node_size` and `edge_width` or you can increase the size of the canvas with `scale=(100, 100)`, for example. All that being said, it is hard to debug comments, so if these suggestions don't solve your issue, ask a question here on SO with the `netgraph` tag or raise an issue on my [github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph).